# how opencsv BeanToCsv resolve line break will split java beans

Tags: opencsv

ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();

```
    CustomerAttribute attr1 = new CustomerAttribute().setAttributeId(123).setAttributeValue("abc,\nbcd");
    CustomerAttribute attr2 = new CustomerAttribute().setAttributeId(123).setAttributeValue("abc");
    list.add(attr1);
    list.add(attr2);
    HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<CustomerAttribute> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
    strategy.setType(CustomerAttribute.class);
    Writer writer = new FileWriter("sample.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    StatefulBeanToCsv<CustomerAttribute> build = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<CustomerAttribute>(writer)
            .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
            .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
            .build();
```

I just set two java beans to convert csv file, but due to the value "abc,\nbcd", the csv file is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8jch.jpg)

I just except two lines because it will cause parse this csv file to java bean error.
how can i resolve this line break in bean field. I don't know witch filed will contains line break, so I can't do check and replace line break.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getAttributeValue() {
    return attributeValue.replaceAll("\n", " ");
}
```

The temporary solution I can think of is
to perform replaceAll on the get method of the line break field that may appear

Comment: https://b-greve.gitbook.io/beginners-guide-to-clean-data/common-csv-problems/line-breaks-in-text-fields looks like useful info assuming you are writing CSV processing to be used by others.  If I understand your question well, whatever solution you use will best take into account the issues raised in that article.  Mentioning them and how this answer handles them would be very helpful.